# how to make custom line break in my code

Tags: image, c#-4.0, radio-button

I have following code in C# which is printing images from db.And through this code images and radio button shows single time in single line.Here is My code

```
foreach (DataRow item in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            divs += @"  <div style="" position:relative; height:100px; width:400px; margin:10px auto;"">
                            <div style=""position:absolute; width:80px; height:80px; top: 10px; left: 130px;"">
                                 <a href=""#"" class=""screenshot"" rel=""images/"+item["namee"].ToString()+@".jpg"" ><img src=""images/" + item["namee"].ToString() + @".jpg"" width=""80px"" height=""80px""  /></a>
                        </div>";
            if(id < 1){
            divs += @"  <div style=""position:absolute; width:231px; left:240px; top:35px; height: 40px;"">
                                <p style="" margin-top:10px; margin-left:20px; ""><input type=""radio"" name=""SSRI"" value=""" + item["namee"].ToString() + @""" /></p>
                            </div>";
            }

            divs += @"<div style=""position:absolute; width:231px; left:100px; bottom:10px; height: 40px;"">

                            </div>
                        </div>";
        }
        Response.Write(divs);
```

By this Code Out Put is like this

```
Images '' radio
Images '' radio
```

But i want that out put should b like this

```
Images '' radio    Images '' radio
Images '' radio    Images '' radio
```

Is there any one can help me to do this. Please Help !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your current code attempts to do what you want, but you should use **[floating divs](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/tutorial0211.htm)**. Remove all the `top` `left` and `position:absolute` you have, and just use `float`, `height` and `width`. Then use the `clear:left;` to a new line.

For example, in your code:

```
int currLine = 0;
foreach (DataRow item in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
      if (currLine % 2 == 0)
      {
         // Every second item, move to a new line
         divs += @"<div style=""clear:float;"" />"
      }  

      divs += @"  <div style=""float:left;  width:400px; margin:10px auto;background:yellow;">
                        <div style=""width:80px; height:80px;background:red;""
                             <a href=""#"" class=""screenshot"" rel=""images/"+item["namee"].ToString()+@".jpg"" ><img src=""images/" + item["namee"].ToString() + @".jpg"" width=""80px"" height=""80px""  /></a>
                    </div>";
        if(id < 1){
        divs += @"  <div style=""width:231px;height: 40px;background:blue;"">
                            <p style="" margin-top:10px; margin-left:20px; ""><input type=""radio"" name=""SSRI"" value=""" + item["namee"].ToString() + @""" /></p>
                        </div>";
        }

        divs += @"<div style=""width:231px; height: 40px;background:green;"">

                        </div>
                    </div>";
    }
    Response.Write(divs);
```

I took the liberty of adding different colored `backgrounds` so you can better learn what does what..